# Scapy IP() custom load

Tags: ip, scapy, packet, packet-sniffers

I am trying to put a custom RS encoded message (which is in bytes) as

```
packet = IP(dst=DESTINATION, src="11.0.0.1")
rs = uni.rs.RSCoder(40, 20)
encoded = rs.encode(raw(packet)).encode('latin1')
packet = packet/Raw(load=encoded)
```

Since I have minimal knowledge of scapy, I used this and the main function is not able to process this packet. I recently found out that the first 20 bytes are of header when I print the above packet I get the following :
`b'E\x00\x00\x14\x00\x01\x00\x00@\x00d\xe7\x0b\x00\x00\x01\x0b\x00\x00\x02\xaa\x9do8\x1dv\xdc@l;m\xcf\x83\xfaa\nW\xa9\xf6+'`

which is the encoded payload and I presume the first 20 bytes are header. Does the packet processor considering the whole packet as a header and not just the first 20 bytes ? I am really not sure of what is happening.

Comment: how do you print it? with method `show`?

Comment: @qouify: I simply used the print() statement of python.

Comment: Try `packet.show()` instead. `print` is useless to view a packet.

Comment: @qouify: As you said I did that and the Raw load: displays the entire byte array as above. Does it mean the load is the 20 byte header ?